# Traer sentencia SQL y pasar a variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta sentencia SQL/PHP

```
echo '¡Hola ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["div"]) . '!';

$sql = "SELECT id_div FROM divisiones WHERE division_name = '$_POST[div]'";
$res = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

Y lo que quiero es pasar el `id_div` que me traiga la sentencia a una variable de php para poder insertarla en un insert que voy a hacer con SQL.

Pero no funciona y creo que es por que tengo mal esta parte que pongo.

¿Como podría hacerlo?

EDIT:

Añado el codigo que uso para insertarla en una sentencia INSERT, no se si esta bien.

```
        mysqli_query($conexion, "insert into result_equipo (id_reseq, id_div, jor, id_eq, puntos, pg, pp, n_p, fecha) VALUES 
    (NULL, '$res', '$_POST[jor]', '$_POST[equipos]', '2', '1', '0', '0', '$_POST[date]')");
```

Gracias

Comment: Hasta ahi el codigo se ve ok.. recibis algun error? ahora res tiene una coleccion de registros que tenes que recorrer (eso si la query funciono ok).

Comment: Hola @gbianchi no me sale ningun error, pero simplemente no me lo inserta en la db (He editado con el insert que hago)

Comment: de donde viene ese `$_POST["div"]` y que estas pasando en el?

Comment: Ese post viene de otro php, y es un nombre en concreto, y lo que hago es sacar de ese nombre el id al que esta asociado para insertarlo en otra tabla. @andygibbs

Comment: $res no es un valor insertable. fijate que devuelve mysqli_query. Devuelve un vector de resultados. no un resultado.

Comment: @gbianchi y como hago para que devuelva el resultado? (Que en el ejemplo que estoy empleando, deberia devolverme un 12)

Comment: Creo recordar que no puedes usar directamente `$_POST[div]` en medio de una cadena, debes cortar la cadena y concatenar con `.`. Aparte, tienes que usar comillas para dar el nombre del indice del array. Ademas yo usaría sentencias preparadas pues ese código es muy vulnerable a inyencciones SQL malignas.

Comment: ¿Por qué nadie le ayuda?, le preguntan sobre cosas que no conoce y le reprochan su código pero nadie aporta nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le falta mucha carne a tu código, te recomendaría un curso en YouTube de PHP.

Ahora, ya no te rompas la cabeza, te dejo el código comentado.

Saludos.

```
<?php

//Primero tienes que validar que llegue un dato, lo hice con una condición ternaria
$div = !empty( $_POST['div'] ) ? $_POST['div'] : null;

//Creas tu consulta
$sql = "SELECT id_div FROM DIVISIONES WHERE division_name = '" . $div . "'";

//Ejecutas la consulta, voy a suponer que tu variable $conexion no tiene problemas
$res = mysqli_query( $conexion, $sql );

//Valida que no haya problemas con la consulta, mysqli_query te regresa un vector de datos o false
if( !$res ){
  echo 'La consulta está mal construida';
}

else{
  //Si la consulta está bien ahora revisa que existan datos
  if( mysqli_num_rows($res) <= 0){
    echo 'No existe información con esta variable';
  }

  else{
    //Si trae datos la consulta entonces ya puedes usarla, hay que sacar los datos
    //Como solo es un dato podemos hacerlo directo, si fueran más, entonces hacemos un while
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $res );

    //Saca la variable, así como la llamaste en tu SQL vendrá el índice en tu resultado
    //Supondré que es un INT o similar, por lo que parsearé, si no es así solo quita (int)
    $in_div = (int) $row['id_div'];

    //Recuerda que por salud del servidor hay que liberar memoria
    mysqli_free_result($res);

    //Ahora si ya puedes usar el id en tu Insert;
    $insert = "insert into result_equipo (id_reseq, id_div, jor, id_eq, puntos, pg, pp, n_p, fecha) VALUES 
    (NULL, '$in_div', '$_POST[jor]', '$_POST[equipos]', '2', '1', '0', '0', '$_POST[date]')";

    //Ejecuta tu INSERT
    mysqli_query($conexion, $insert);

    //Vamos validar la inserción
    if( mysqli_affected_rows($conexion)<=0 ){
      echo 'No se insertó nada';
    }

    else{
      //En caso que necesites el ID que se insertó lo puedes hacer así
      $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);
      echo 'Inserción correcta, el ID es: ' . $last_id;
    }

    //Recuerda cerrar la conexión
    mysqli_close( $conexion );
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Gracias, aun soy junior y me queda por aprender, lo conseguí hacer mandando por POST en el anterior .php (del que trae el div) en un input hidden con el dato que necesito. Pero este, tu metodo, es mucho mas profesional.

Answer (score 1):

no puedes meter un array asi no mas directamente en tu sentencia `SQL`
la forma correcta seria entre llaves `{}` o concatenado con `.` asi

```
$sql = "SELECT id_div FROM divisiones WHERE division_name = '{$_POST[div]}'";


  mysqli_query($conexion, "insert into result_equipo (id_reseq, id_div, jor, id_eq, puntos, pg, pp, n_p, fecha) VALUES 
    (NULL, '$res', '{$_POST[jor]}', '{$_POST[equipos]}', '2', '1', '0', '0', '{$_POST[date]}')");
```

o asi

```
 $sql = "SELECT id_div FROM divisiones WHERE division_name = '{$_POST[div]}'";


      mysqli_query($conexion, "insert into result_equipo (id_reseq, id_div, jor, id_eq, puntos, pg, pp, n_p, fecha) VALUES 
        (NULL, '$res', '".$_POST[jor]."', '".$_POST[equipos]."', '2', '1', '0', '0', '".$_POST[date]."')");
```